# How can I get a python program to read and serve up different data values from a table/external file?

Tags: python, datasource, external, minecraft

I'm trying to write a program to be used with Minecraft, that will let me search for item id's of any in-game item by entering it's name.

For example: Searching for "MOSSY STONE" would return something like "MOSSY COBBLESTONE ID = 98:1"

I'm new to Python and coding in general (save some negligible basic HTML...). Would it be possible to link an external text file to my .py somehow, so that when a "MOSSY STONE" is executed, the search term is cross-referenced with the text file, and the corresponding item ID (in this case 98:1), is returned?

[Edit]

- I haven't created the .txt file yet. Originally it was going to be a table, but I guess something like

> Item 1 - Item 1 ID
>   Item 2 - Item 2 ID
>   Item 3 - Item 3 ID
>   etc...

- I've coded a few simple things in Python before, mostly just test programs with math equations (I wrote something to calculate distance in minecraft using:
  **sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2))**

Comment: As this question stands it is not a good fit for SO. check out the faq to see why. Also, if you have a file with all the names and codes in it can you edit your question to show the format of the file?

Comment: Before you ask us, try yourself. If you got really limited knowledge of Python, I'd recommend reading (or as I prefer, watching from youtube) a tutorial set. Also we **must** know the formatting of your file.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to help you when you hav'nt given any detail. Also, how much python do you know. You should really try to get some basic understanding if you have not yet got it. This is a good start: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk

Anyway this is a quick and dirty sample of what you try to achive. If you have a file named `testdata.txt` looking like this:

```
STONE A > 11:1
STONE B > 12:2
MOSSY STONE > 98:1
STONE C > 13:3
```

You could read it like this:

```
import re  # For use later
datafile = open('C://testdata.txt', 'r')
data = datafile.read()
```

Search for a certain id like this:

```
prop = 'MOSSY STONE'
match = re.search(prop + '\s>\s(\d+:\d+)', data)
if match:
    id = match.group(1)
    print id
else:
    print prop, 'not found!'
```

Answer (score 0):

weird... weird question)
anyways that may be helpful
[Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

[HTML parsers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)